# Lua for loop reduce i? Weird behavior

Tags: for-loop, lua, decrement

Can someone explain me this?

```
for i = 1, 5 do
  print(i)
  i = i - 1
  print(i)
end
```

Output is:

```
1
0
2
1
3
2
and so forth
```

I exspected i to alter between 1 and 0. But obviously it keeps increasing as if I did not change it at all. What's going on?

I have to delete an i'th table element every now and then. So the next element to process would be i again. In C I would just write --i at the end of my loop content. Any official way in lua? :)

Comment: Don't use the loop control variable for it. Use some other condition (even something that is always true with a manual break condition).

Comment: You could also track a difference: `local d=0; for/do i=i-d; if/then d=d+1 end ... end`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loop index (`i` in your case) is a variable local to the body of the loop, so any modifications you do to it have no effect on the loop conditions or the next element being processed (for the `for` loop).

If you need to have better control over the index to delete elements and keep processing, you should use the `while` loop form. See [For Statement](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5) section for details.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a `while(true)` loop instead? Then you'll have to break manually, but that might work.

```
local i = 5
while(true) do
    print(i)
    i = i - 1
    if (i == 0) then break; end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to set the loop control variable causes a failsafe behavior.

I can't find it in the Language Incompatibility section of recent versions of the manual but I recall it being listed somewhere as a change. It was more of a formalization of previous undefined behavior.

If you are really curious, see the listing of your program from `luac`. The loop control variable is given an internal name so it can't be changed. If the same name is used in an assignment, a local variable is synthesized as a stand-in. It prevents unintentionally causing the `for` to become infinite.

You need another kind of loop.